# Python ElementTree: Parsing a string and getting ElementTree instance

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a string containing XML data that is returned from an http request.

I am using [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse the data, and I want to then search recursively for an element.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319385/need-help-using-xpath-in-elementtree), I can only search recursively with `result.findall()` if `result` is of type `ElementTree` rather than type `Element`.

Now `xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring()` , used to parse the string, returns an `Element` object, while `xml.etree.ElementTree.parse()`, used to parse a *file*, returns an `ElementTree` object.

**My question is then: How can I parse the string and get an `ElementTree` instance?** (without any madness like writing to a temporary file)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you use `ElementTree.fromstring()` what you're getting back is basically the root of the tree, so if you create a new tree like this `ElementTree.ElementTree(root)` you'll get you're looking for.

So, to make it clearer:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree.ElementTree(ElementTree.fromstring(<your_xml_string>))
```

or:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring, ElementTree
tree = ElementTree(fromstring(<your_xml_string>))
```

Comment: I just want to add - for those using lxml - that in lxml (where an element always belongs to a document/tree, even if implicit), you can use the getrootttree() method.

Comment: Thanks! Really annoying API design in etree, to have different types of output just depending on the input source. Really confusing :(

Comment: This really isn't very clear in the documentation. "fromstring() parses XML from a string directly into an Element, which is the root element of the parsed tree. Other parsing functions may create an ElementTree."

Answer (score 8):

Turn your string into a file-like object and use `ElementTree.parse`:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from cStringIO import StringIO

tree = ElementTree.parse(StringIO(string))
```

Comment: Great, this is the one that I was looking for. :-)